# Energy-temperature relation for electrons in metals

Tags: electrons, temperature, plasma-physics

I would like to find the average  electron temperature of a metal given the electrons' energy, the density of ions and the electron number density Which models are available, where should I start?  Is there a model which covers a wide temperature range from close to zero to plasma or should I do ab initio calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with the ideal gas of fermions, disregarding the ions except for giving charge neutrality. In ordinary metals, the average kinetic energy of the electrons is the a function of density ($n^{2/3}$), several electron-volts per electron. As this is much higher than $kT$ at boiling temperatures of any metal, temperature has almost no effect on this. It is only at the lowest temperatures that the electronic specific head can be measured as a small term linear in temperature.